# how can I access laravel .env file from a npm packge?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, composer-php

I'm developing a bundle of a composer packages plus a npm package. This bundle is very specific, it's targeting only Laravel apps.

I'd like to access `.env` file from `npm package`, but I'm not able to find a way to detect where my app's `.env` file is located.

I repeat: I am able to read it using

```
require().config(..file path...)
```

but I am here to ask :

**how to find a way to detect the path of `.env` file of the laravel app which required my node package?**

> I have no malicious intent, simply I'd like to import automatically the DB connection configuration.

Comment: Doesn't the .env file always added in the root of your laravel project? I am not sure I totally get your question so maybe my question is a bit out of topic.

Comment: I would use the cwd and maybe mention it in the docs (i also thought like __dirname and traverse up.. but that's not really reliable.)

Comment: Yes, actually I'm using relative traverse up but I was hoping for a more reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side you can detect the location of the env file by calling

```php
App::environmentFilePath()
```

Comment: My question is different: I must detect .env file from inside a node js package, so from a js file